# Graceful ways to break away from a conversation

Tags: word-choice, conversation

**Closing a Conversation**

I was just in a telephone call with a Chinese person and I attempted to say something like:

xiè xiè nín de lái diàn

谢谢您的来电

Had I said this in English, the caller would have recognised this as a closing statement (an attempt to end the conversation gracefully). The caller did not discontinue the conversation at this point so I assume my word choice may not have been correct. How might I have closed the conversation using a more appropriate phrase or sentence?

Similarly, I've seen CLSE questions about breaking the ice (starting a conversation) but none about how to gracefully close a conversation. I would appreciate any help in this area and I do understand that different regions will have variations (all of which I welcome).

**Update**

Thanks for the answers below and feel free to add more. I make use of this in building my grammar and appreciate the efforts very much. I also received this alternative as well:

```
wǒ men gǎi tiān zài tán bā 
我們改天再談吧
*We'll talk about it another day*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some phrases to make it clear, such as:

> 好的，我知道了。谢谢您的来电。

If you're in intimate relationship, you can just say:

> 那就这样？

Answer (score 4):

It usually depends on the situation. If it was a company telling me about a product I might be interested in, and I hear them out, I usually end with 谢谢,我再考虑考虑

if it's one of my my friends, I usually make an excuse such as have to go now, have to sleep, have to eat etc... and add something like 我们哪天接着聊吧, or 回头见

If talking to my parents, I usually say 就这件事, or 没有别的事, etc

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence 谢谢您的来电 is technically right to close a conversation. 谢谢您的来电 translates to English is 'thank you for your call'. The caller should end your call, are you sure you pronounced it correctly?

Chinese normally won't use '谢谢您的来电' to end a call. We often use an excuse to close the conversation, for example "I have to go now, call you later".

Comment: Would you mind adding some examples in Chinese? I am still working on proper word selection so this would help very much.

Comment: I haven't speak Chinese for a year(I am a Chinese!!). If you say "I have to go now, see you later" would be: 我要走了，再見!

Answer (score 1):

IRL or on the telephone you can always say something like

不好意思，有点事...

Usually 比较自觉的人 will know what the deal is